# Managing User Secrets with Azure KeyVault and Visual Studio not working for ASP .Net Core

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, azure-keyvault

Based on steps from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/key-vault/vs-key-vault-add-connected-service) and [here](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Visual-Studio-Toolbox/Managing-User-Secrets)

I get the following error when I add new KeyVault in Connected services. I am using VS 15.8.1 Community edition. asp.net core 2.1

> "Could not retrive Key Vault information. The hyperlink on this page
>   might not  work as expected and UI might have stale or no information.
>   Please check the activity log for more information.
>   C:\Users\kumar\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_536ef4bf\ActivityLog.xml"

[image: Key Vault Error Message]

I am not getting squiggly in appsetting.json for setting it to azure key vault.

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "InstrumentationKey": "dummyaapinsightkey-cxds3-4001-953f-sf323sdfw32d"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about this error. Looks like some connectivity problem.

But instead of using `KeyVault` as **Connected Service** I'd recommend  you can use the configurable model of KeyVault (Without having connected service) for retrieving the secrets

By using connected service it's difficult to change the configuration of KeyVault when you deploy into production

I've [written an article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51871.managing-secrets-in-web-apps-net-core-2-x.aspx#AzureKeyVault_Secrets) where you can use AzureKeyVault to retrieve your secrets without using connected service

Install the below NuGet package

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault -Version 2.1.1
```

You just need to change the Program.cs as like below

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
             WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                 .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
                 {
                     var builtConfig = config.Build();

                     config.AddAzureKeyVault(
                         $"https://{builtConfig["Vault"]}.vault.azure.net/",
                         builtConfig["ClientId"],
                         builtConfig["ClientSecret"]);
                 })
                 .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
```

appsetting.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "Vault": "myKeyVault",
  "ClientId": "xxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx",
  "ClientSecret": "xxxxxxx="
}
```

---

**Update:**

Now using the Managed Identity you can easily Integrate the Keyvault without even using ClientId and Client Secrets

Read more about: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/app-service-msi-keyvault-dotnet/keyvault-msi-appservice-sample/

Comment: but keeping clientID and ClientSecret on appsetting.json equally insecure? If we upload this to github repo would we not still be exposing all other secrets?

Comment: @kumar you can use azurepipelines to deploy the secrets from keyvault directly into your application, see my another [article here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/52459.azuredevops-deploying-secrets-from-azure-pipelines.aspx)

Comment: @kumar see my update using managed identity you even don't need client id and clientsecrets